# Windows: Boost and CMake

Tags: windows, boost, cmake, mingw

I've tried for a long time to figure out the problem, but I can not.. thus I am here, and I am sorry.

Some information:

- My system is Windows 7, 64-bit professional with Visual Studio 10, and MinGW
- I compiled Boost (1.53.0) using:

  ```
  bootstrap.bat mingw 
  .\b2 --prefix=C:\boost toolset=gcc -j4 link=shared
  .\b2 --prefix=C:\boost toolset=gcc -j4 link=shared install
  ```
- My install looks like:

  ```
  C:\boost
      include\boost-1_53\boost -- headers
      lib\ -- libraries, both dll and dll.a
  ```

  - `ls -la` output of library (truncated for length)

    ```
    $ ls -la 
    total 124249 
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 kevin Administrators    43218 Mar  5 22:07 libboost_atomic-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll
    -rw-r--r-- 1 kevin Administrators     1790 Mar  5 22:07 libboost_atomic-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll.a
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 kevin Administrators    47785 Mar  5 22:07 libboost_atomic-mgw46-mt-d-1_53.dll
    -rw-r--r-- 1 kevin Administrators     1802 Mar  5 22:07 libboost_atomic-mgw46-mt-d-1_53.dll.a
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 kevin Administrators    87319 Mar  5 22:07 libboost_chrono-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll
    ```
- My CMake file is as follows for boost related parts:
      cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
      project(hc12)

  ```
  set(Boost_DEBUG 1)

  #need to add more components, used for testing
  find_package(Boost 1.53.0 COMPONENTS system chrono thread filesystem unit_test_framework signals REQUIRED )

  if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
      message(fatal_error "Boost was not found. See FindBoost.cmake for details.")
  endif()

  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

  # snip for brievity

  add_library(hc12 SHARED ${libhc12_srcs} )
  target_link_libraries(hc12 ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
      ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} 
      ${Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY}
      ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY}
      ${Boost_SIGNALS_LIBRARY}
      ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY}
    )


  #--dependencies
  add_executable(test ${test_srcs})

  add_dependencies(test hc12)

  target_link_libraries(test hc12 ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
      ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} 
      ${Boost_CHRONO_LIBRARY}
      ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY}
      ${Boost_SIGNALS_LIBRARY}
      ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY}
    )
  ```

  - The file actually has a lot more, but most of it is custom command garbage for auto-generation of code.

The output of `cmake ..` is:

```
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
Setting to be debug
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:56
6 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:56
8 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:57
0 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS =
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:57
2 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME =
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:57
4 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS =
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:57
6 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS =
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:64
4 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:64
6 ]   BOOST_ROOT = c:/Boost
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:64
8 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = c:/boost/include/
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:65
0 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR =
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:65
2 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53
CMake Error at c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoos
t.cmake:732 (file):
  file STRINGS file "C:/Program Files/boost/boost/version.hpp" cannot be
  read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)


-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:73
4 ] location of version.hpp: C:/Program Files/boost/boost/version.hpp
CMake Error at c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoos
t.cmake:746 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " / 100000": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_DIVIDE, expecting exp_OPENPARENT or exp_NUMBER (2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)


CMake Error at c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoos
t.cmake:747 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " / 100 % 1000": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_DIVIDE, expecting exp_OPENPARENT or exp_NUMBER (2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)


CMake Error at c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoos
t.cmake:748 (math):
  math cannot parse the expression: " % 100": syntax error, unexpected
  exp_MOD, expecting exp_OPENPARENT or exp_NUMBER (2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)


-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:75
4 ] version.hpp reveals boost ..
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:78
6 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER =
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:79
6 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:83
9 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:84
1 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:88
4 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = c:/Boost/lib;c:/Boost/stage/lib;C:/Program File
s/boost/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/../lib;C:/Program Files/boost/stage/lib;C:/bo
ost/lib;C:/boost;C:\Program Files (x86)/boost/boost___/lib;C:\Program Files (x86
)/boost/boost__/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)/boost/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)/boos
t;/sw/local/lib
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:96
2 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-mt-;boost_system-mt;boost
_system-mt-;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:99
4 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-mt-d-;boost_system-mt-d;boo
st_system-mt-d-;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:96
2 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_chrono-mt-;boost_chrono-mt;boost
_chrono-mt-;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:99
4 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_chrono-mt-d-;boost_chrono-mt-d;boo
st_chrono-mt-d-;boost_chrono-mt-d;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:96
2 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_thread-mt-;boost_thread-mt;boost
_thread-mt-;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:99
4 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_thread-mt-d-;boost_thread-mt-d;boo
st_thread-mt-d-;boost_thread-mt-d;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:96
2 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-mt-;boost_filesys
tem-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:99
4 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-mt-d-;boost_filesys
tem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d-;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_
filesystem
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:96
2 ] Searching for UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_unit_test_framework
-mt-;boost_unit_test_framework-mt;boost_unit_test_framework-mt-;boost_unit_test_
framework-mt;boost_unit_test_framework
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:99
4 ] Searching for UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_unit_test_framework-m
t-d-;boost_unit_test_framework-mt-d;boost_unit_test_framework-mt-d-;boost_unit_t
est_framework-mt-d;boost_unit_test_framework-mt;boost_unit_test_framework
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:96
2 ] Searching for SIGNALS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_signals-mt-;boost_signals-mt;bo
ost_signals-mt-;boost_signals-mt;boost_signals
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:99
4 ] Searching for SIGNALS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_signals-mt-d-;boost_signals-mt-d;
boost_signals-mt-d-;boost_signals-mt-d;boost_signals-mt;boost_signals
-- [ c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:11
08 ] Boost_FOUND = FALSE
CMake Error at c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoos
t.cmake:1192 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: ..

  Boost include path: C:/Program Files/boost

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_system
          boost_chrono
          boost_thread
          boost_filesystem
          boost_unit_test_framework
          boost_signals

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)


fatal_errorBoost was not found. See FindBoost.cmake for details.
CMake Error at c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPack
ageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (message):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE
  QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE QT_LIBRARY_DIR QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStan
dardArgs.cmake:291 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1223 (F
IND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  src/tools/InstructParser/CMakeLists.txt:7 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have tried declaring `BOOST_ROOT` and the `BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` to no avail.

I will answer all and any questions for help.

Comment: Show at least one boost library name, e.g. `system`

Comment: Added into original post!

Comment: try to set `Boost_COMPILER`  to `46`. Also, I presume that for your project you use cmake generator for MinGW and not for visual studio.

Comment: I just found in your output that you don't provide generator to cmake. You should clean folder where you generated cmake files and run the following: `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..`

Comment: Looking through the output, I've gotten it to find the includes, but it still doesn't find the libraries. This is because they are named differently, these are named: `libboost_serialization-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll` and cmake wants: `boost_system46-mt-d-1_53;boost_system46-
mt-d;boost_system-mt-d-1_53;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt;boost_system`

Comment: You didn't specify generator via -G command parameter, you should do it. Run cmake without arguments to list all possible strings to -G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I had to do to make everything work as expected:

1. From **Visual Studio Prompt**: Recompile boost with the following command: `.\b2 --prefix=C:\boost toolset=gcc -j4 link=shared threading=multi --ignore-python --ignore-mpi --layout=tagged`

   The `layout=tagged` causes boost to make the libraries of the form `libboost_system-mt.dll` which just denotes that it is multi-threaded. It removes the extraneous parts of the name which were causing problems before.
2. From **MinGW shell**: To configure the project from `build` (assuming that the project top-level directory is in `..`): `CC=gcc CXX=g++ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=~/Qt/ -DQJSON_DIR=~/qjson ..`

   The `QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE` and `QJSON_DIR` variables were only required due to my project. For most, you should only need to do `CC=gcc CXX=g++ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..` to compile a simple project with boost.

   I got a few errors as I did this, but I just `rm -rf`'d the build directory and started from scratch to fix the errors.
3. To actually compile, instead of using `make` you *must* use `mingw32-make.exe` (or what ever your MinGW installation has) to compile, *from MinGW Shell*.

Now all I need to do is figure out how to properly link to boost binary libraries to run my custom code-generator from within CMake.. :(

Thanks for the help!